# Somali encoding

Tags: python, twitter, encoding, utf-8

I am crawling for tweets from Somalia on Twitter. This is what I am getting:

```
T\u00fcrk K\u0131z\u0131lay\u0131 Genel Ba\u015fkan\u0131m\u0131z Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yar\u0131n sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canl\u0131 yay\u0131n konu\u011fu olacak... @TurkKizilayi
```

I tracked down the original tweet and this is actually how it reads:

```
Türk Kızılayı Genel Başkanımız Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yarın sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canlı yayın konuğu olacak... @TurkKizilayi
```

How do I automatically convert the version I am getting to the correct encoding?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you printing out the string?  What is `map(ord, tweetdata[:20])`?

Comment: How exactly get the data? The encoding should be specified in the result of your request or in some API documentation. Guessing encodings is hard if possible at all. Please show more details what you're actually doing and what you have already tried.

Comment: I am using this tool: https://github.com/chbrown/twilight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks very much like a `unicode`: (note the `u` before the double-quotes.)

```
In [41]: print(u"T\u00fcrk K\u0131z\u0131lay\u0131 Genel Ba\u015fkan\u0131m\u0131z Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yar\u0131n sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canl\u0131 yay\u0131n konu\u011fu olacak... @TurkKizilayi")
Türk Kızılayı Genel Başkanımız Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yarın sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canlı yayın konuğu olacak... @TurkKizilayi
```

If what you have is a `str` (as opposed to a `unicode`), then you can decode it with `raw_unicode_escape`:

```
In [43]: print("T\u00fcrk K\u0131z\u0131lay\u0131 Genel Ba\u015fkan\u0131m\u0131z Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yar\u0131n sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canl\u0131 yay\u0131n konu\u011fu olacak... @TurkKizilayi".decode('raw_unicode_escape'))
Türk Kızılayı Genel Başkanımız Sn. @AhmetLutfiAkar yarın sabah 08:00'e TV8'de canlı yayın konuğu olacak... @TurkKizilayi
```

Comment: Thanks! if I ihave a variable x set to T\u00fcrk K\u0131z\u0131lay\u0131

Comment: for example x = T\u00fcrk K\u0131z\u0131lay\u0131, how do I do the print syntactically print u x?

Comment: Given a `str`, `x`, you can't tack a `u` onto it to make it `unicode`. Instead, you need to call the `x.decode` method as I showed above.